# How to write linq to get most recent incoming event records

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

var events = context.Events.........

Events has a property 'DueDate' (Datetime)

I want to select most recent 5 records, how to write such a query? Thanks

Comment: Does DueDate reflect the "recentness" of the record?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are interested in the Events that are closest to day you could do this:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
var events = context.Events
                    .OrderBy(e => Math.Abs((today - e.DueDate).Days))
                    .Take(5)
                    .ToList();
```

This takes the events that are the least number of days away from today (in the past OR future).

If you wanted events that are most recent but only in the future, you could do:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
var events = context.Events
                    .Where(e => e.DueDate >= today)
                    .OrderBy(e => (e.DueDate - today).Days)
                    .Take(5)
                    .ToList();
```

**Edit:**

If you use LINQ to Entities `DateTime` manipulation is not directly supported, but if you use SQL server something like [DateDiff](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466305.aspx) should work (untested you'll have to try out yourself):

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
var events = context.Events
                    .Where(e => e.DueDate >= today)
                    .OrderBy(e => System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions.DateDiff("d", e.DueDate, today))
                    .Take(5)
                    .ToList();
```

If that doesn't work you can always get your data first, then filter with LINQ to objects, which has the added benefits that you're not tying yourself to SQL Server - but obviously it's not very efficient:

```
DateTime today = DateTime.Now;
var futureEvents = context.Events
                          .Where(e => e.DueDate >= today);
                          .ToList();   

var filteredEvent = futureEvents 
                    .OrderBy(e => (e.DueDate - today).Days)
                    .Take(5)
                    .ToList();
```

Comment: Could you help me write in this way: First filter all the due date, that the duedate must greater than today, and then order by accending, select top 5?

Comment: Edited my answer to do just that - this will order by days from "today" ascending, if you wanted it to be more fine grained you could use the `Ticks` property instead of `Days` in the OrderBy clause.

Comment: I got this: DbArithmeticExpression arguments must have a numeric common type.

Comment: Added to my answer to (hopefully) make it work for LNIQ to Entities

Answer (score 1):

One way to write it:

`var events = context.Events.OrderByDescending(e=>e.DueDate).Take(5);`

Comment: Would that gonna select top 5 recoreds that have 'biggest' Duedate?

Comment: I want to select 5 most recent records that close to today.

Comment: Perhaps that should've been in your question, then :)